# Helm error from Airflow : "Error: no objects visited"

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

```
helm install airflow airflow-stable/airflow --version "8.8.0" --namespace "data-platform"    --values custom-values.yaml
```

it gives this error --

`Error: no objects visited`

so I type the helm repo update then it return --

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCznW.png)

Comment: It’s unclear what the issue is. After running helm repo update as shown in your attached screenshot, do you still encounter the error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Also remember that Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions (see the [help/on-topic]); if you're just trying to `helm install` prepackaged software, another site like [devops.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.